# Nontrivial Matrix-estimate

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I try to proof the following estimate:
\begin{align} 
h' W^{-1} H W^{-1} h \geq c h' H h \qquad c>0, \qquad\qquad (1)
\end{align}
where $h\in\mathbb{R}^{K-1}$ and $W,H\in\mathbb{R}^{(K-1)\times(K-1)}$, such that the components of $h,H$ are given by
\begin{align*}
h_k = q_{k+1} - q_k, 
\quad H_{k,j} = \begin{cases}q_{k+1}^2 + q_{k}^2 ,& l=k \\
    -q_{k+1}^2 , & l = k+1 \\
    -q_k^2 , & l  =k-1 \end{cases}. 
\end{align*}
with $q_k>0$ and
\begin{align*}
W = \begin{pmatrix} 4 && 1 && 0 && \ldots && 0\\
1 && 4 && 1 && \ldots && 0\\
0 && 1 && \ddots && && \vdots\\ 
\vdots && \vdots && && 4 && 1\\
0 && 0 && \ldots && 1 && 4
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

In fact i know, that $W,H$ are both positive definite and $W$ holds the bounds 
\begin{align}
\underline{c}\|v\|_2^2 \leq v'Wv \leq \overline{c}\|v\|_2^2\qquad\qquad (2)
\end{align}
for $\underline{c},\overline{c}\in(0,\infty)$ independently of the dimension $K$.

Moreover one can rewrite $h$ and $H$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
 h = \sum_{k=1}^{K} v_k q_k \quad\text{and}\quad
 H = \delta^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{K} q_k^2v_kv_k^T,
\quad\text{with}\quad
 v_k=\begin{cases} -e_1 , & k=1 \\ e_{k-1}-e_k , & k = 2,\ldots,K-1 \\ e_{K-1} , & k = K \end{cases}.
\end{align*}
Here $e_k$ denotes the unit basis vector with $k^{th}$ component equal to $1$ and $v_kv_k'$ is the dyad with only one non-zero eigenvalue $\|v_k\|_2^2$.

I think that there should be an "easy" algebraic proof, using basically estimate (2), especially sine numerical simulations have shown, that the constant in (1) can be chosen as $\overline{c}^2$.
As an additional information (which i think is not necesarry for the proof) is given by
\begin{align*}
q_k = \frac{1}{x_k-x_{k-1}} \quad\text{with} \quad \sum_0^K x_k = 1
\end{align*}

Thanks for any advice!!!